# how to fit 255 width table in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to view the web-page in UIWebView in iOS. Below is the link I am trying to view.

http://almaktab.com/forms/flight.html

**The problem is width of table is 255px and when I open this in webview, it covers only half screen which looks odd.** Below is the code I am using for viewing web page in UIWebView.

```
-(void)openWebPage:(NSString*)address {
    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    myWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    myWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    myWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    [myWebView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
}
```

I want to stretch this webview so that form can fit for whole page.

---

I know solution for this would be `width=100%`, but client don't want to do any changes in their website now. Client asked to do changes in iOS only.

Any idea how this can be get done.

---

### Screenshot (myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;)

[image]

### Screenshot (myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;)

[image]

Comment: set the UIWebView property scalesPageToFit to FALSE.

Comment: May be you should calculate of center for myWebView.frame?

Comment: will you attache the screen shot. please.

Comment: @PrateekPrem : Attached...

Comment: @MuditBajpai : Done, attached is the screenshot... but its not going full screen

Comment: can you check the webview frame position? or try to add this line webView.frame=self.view.bounds;

Comment: @MuditBajpai : Same result even after adding `webView.frame=self.view.bounds;`

Comment: is there any id or class used for table in html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

And in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
[view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('table3').width='100%'"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have not use AutoresizingMask.